# Removing html tags from an xml snippet?

Tags: c#, html, xml

I am looking to strip out HTML tags from snippet below. This is a sample, the XML file schema can change and so can the XML and is not static.
I would like to preserve XML node(s)
Is there a way to do this automatically, without using external libraries/tools/etc?

```
<house>
  <welcome>This is a <b>great</b> house.</welcome>
</house>
```

Comment: It seems likely that this is going to involve using `Replace` with a long list of `HTML` tags.

Comment: @MartinParkin This is what i thought...but wanted to know there is definitely no other way. Thanks

Comment: This comes up time and time again. Parse your XML with XDocument then treat HTML like HTML and use HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: @paqogomez The question specifically stated _without using external libraries/tools/etc_.  The HTML Agility Pack is an external library.

Comment: Thanks @paqogomez I would prefer to do it without any external lib/tool. I will keep it open to see if there is any other option

Comment: @MartinParkin, so true.  As HTML is not a regular grammar it cannot be parsed with regular expressions effectively.  There is nothing native that does.  A library is your only option.

Comment: How much do you know about the HTML tags in the nodes? Will they always be well formed? Will they allways have no attributes? Will they always be from a small subset of simple HTML elements or could there be complex structures like Tables and Lists? If you **know** that your limited to a small set of well formed, with no arrtibutes, simple HTML structures you *might* be able to get away without an external library. Otherwise use the right tool for the job, which would be a parser like HTML agility pack.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

```
string yourXml = ".....";
System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(yourXml);
string yourXmlWithoutTags = xmlDoc.InnerText;
string someContentWithoutTags = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("root/house").InnerText;
```

etc...

Comment: unfortunately the xml is not stactic and can have different structure to the one mentioned above, so this solution won't work

Answer (score 0):

While I advocate the use of [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for HTML, based on your example, XDocument pulls out the html without a problem.

```
  var xmlString = @"<house>
                      <welcome>This is a <b>great</b> house.</welcome>
                    </house>";
  var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
  var welcome = xml.Descendants("house").Elements("welcome").First().Value;
  Console.Write(welcome);
  //This is a great house.
```

This is probably because when `Parse` occurs, the `<b>` tags are removed.  `Load` would not behave this way.

An HTML agility pack method would look something like this:

```
public string StripTags(string input) {
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(input ?? "");
    return doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Parsing is a bit interesting. Let me explore that option.